# Не сохраняются данные postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql9.5

Ubuntu 16.04, Postgres 9.5, Django 1.11.1.

Не происходит сохранение данных в БД, само приложение ни на что не ругается.

В логах `postgresql-9.5-main.log` обнаружил следующее:

```
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1026-2] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1026-3] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1040-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1037-1] LOG:  shutting down
2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK [1037-2] LOG:  database system is shut down
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1056-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-16 18:26:42 MSK
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1056-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1038-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1061-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2017-06-16 18:26:57 MSK [1273-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2017-06-16 21:35:42 MSK [5836-1] user@user LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2017-06-17 17:37:27 MSK [26684-1] user@user LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2017-06-17 17:37:27 MSK [26678-1] user@user LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2017-06-17 17:37:27 MSK [26676-1] user@user LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Перезагрузка постгреса как и самой системы ни к чему не привели.

При этом данные из БД отображаются нормально. Я могу зайти по логину и паролю, но сохранить ничего не получается. Просто обновляется форма, а сохранённых данных в ней нет.

Не могу понять, в чём проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих попыток выяснить в чём причина, после переустановки постгреса с дампом базы данных, и даже после переустановки операционной системы проблема не решилась, и я стал рыть дальше, в поисках причины.

В конечном итоге, мне удалось выяснить её. Проблему создавала простейшая оплошность допущенная мною при экспериментах с конфигом Nginx:

```
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
```

Именно метод POST кешировался следующей директивой:

```
proxy_cache_valid 200 302 1m;
```

Из-за чего данные не сохранялись в БД.